# scheduling Push Notifications

Tags: ios

I want to schedule the push notification in IOS.
I think it will be done with third party.
There are several providers to do this. but I can not find out the correct way.
I need a good advise from you.

Comment: If you want to do it locally.. then it can be done via local notificationas, if you  want to do it via server.. then you must have your own server from where you can schedule and send push notificaitons to user

Comment: You need to supply more information. What have you already tried? What specific problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://onesignal.com, which has a nice rest-api for scheduling remote notifications across many platforms including iOS

Comment: good response. The sdk really schedule the remote push notifications for free. But in order to use it, the phone should be jailbreaked. Because it uses the cydia scheme. In real life users don't like to install the extra installation. Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently using on my iPhone that's not jailbroken.

Comment: Can you let me know your IOS version? It happens in IOS 9.1. Up until IOS 9 special scheme such as cydia is allowed. But not in IOS 9.1. Or your phone could be already jailbreaked by some app containing cydia app.

Comment: It's v9.2.1, I've had a look at the OneSignal documentation and they say the SDK supports iOS 6.1 and above. The link to that is here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions-1

Answer (score 0):

You can use CRON, if you own a hosting.